# How to run a callback inside animation in AnimeJS

Tags: javascript, animejs

Does anybody know how to run a custom code inside of animation in animejs?
I know that there is a 'run' callback (but it runs code not counting the time offset)
For example, in gsap there is a 'call' function, where you can run a custom function with given delay.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution
It was really trivial)

```
.add({
        targets: planet,
        begin: function (){ playPlanet()}
    }, 3100)
```